# AssertJ - how to check that an element is in a collection?

Tags: java, unit-testing, assertj

Is there a way to check that an object is an element of some collection with AssertJ? Something like

```java
assertThat(actualObject).isElementOf(collectionWithExpectedOptions);
```

I could do

```java
assertThat(collectionWithExpectedOptions).contains(actualObject);
```

But I think there is a convention that the argument of `assertThat()` should be the *actual* rather than the expected thing.

Comment: I don't think there is. "contains" is a property of the collection, not of the object, therefore it makes more sense to assert a fact about the collection. The object could be in many different collections (or could exist several times in a single collection).

Comment: There is `isIn()`, see the answer by Joel Costigliola.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `isIn`:

```
Iterable<Ring> elvesRings = list(vilya, nenya, narya);

// assertion will pass:
assertThat(nenya).isIn(elvesRings);
```